# RichFaces dataScroller action confilicts with the JSF commandButton and ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I use JSF2 with RichFaces. On my form I have dataTable with dataScroller and commandButton with ajax. The problem is whenever I click the dataScroller to go to the next page the ajax activates. This is wrong. I want to activate ajax only when I click on the Submit button.

```
<h:form id="approveForm"> 
    <h:panelGrid>

        <rich:dataTable width="100%" value="#{customBean.approvalList}"
            var="item"  id="table" rowClasses="odd-row, even-row"
            rows="5" styleClass="my-custom-table">     

            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="WorkItems List" />
            </f:facet>  

            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Comments</f:facet>
                <h:inputText name="comment" />
            </rich:column>        
        </rich:dataTable>

        <rich:dataScroller for="table" maxPages="5"         
            fastStep="3"styleClass="pagination-right"/> 
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{customBean.submit_complete}"
            class="btn primaryBtn btn btn-success btn-next" 
            onclick="function_submit();"> 

            <a4j:ajax execute="@form" render="pnlResult"
                onevent="handleDisableButton" />
        </h:commandButton>

        <a4j:status>
            <f:facet name="start">
                <h:outputText id="test" value="In Progress...." />
                <h:graphicImage value="../../images/progress.gif" alt="Working" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="stop">
            </f:facet>
        </a4j:status>

        <h:outputText id="pnlResult" value="#{customBean.result}" escape="false" /> 
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: You can remove ajax and javascript from commanButton and return null in action. As result full page will be re-rendered.

Comment: Can you reduce the code to show only the important parts? And when you say the ajax activates what is happening? As opposed to what you expect to happen.

Comment: I reduced the code. Form has Submit button, when I click on the Submit button the form has to run the ajax part. but now with dataScroller when I click on the numbers of scroller it's like I clicked on the Submit button.

Comment: We don't know what "it's like I clicked" means, is the dataScroller executing some functionality you don't want? DataScroller fires its own ajax request but it shouldn't interfere with the rest of the page.